# What does 「はだ」 mean?

Tags: words

It is a situation which a salesperson announces to a group of people to attract them to buy his goods

Here is the full sentence.

ああいう物{もの}の値{ね}うちのわかる決{けつ}断{だん}力{りょく}さえた少{しょう}年{ねん}が日{に}本{ほん}にいるっていうこと**はだ**

Actually, there are 3 text bubbles adjacent to each other in the same panel and I brought only the sentence from the last bubble into the above line.

Below here are the 2 first sentences from those bubbles.

First bubble: いや おそれ いりました!

Second bubble: これだけいる おとなどもが買{か}いしぶって いる中{なか}で あんな子{こ}どもが さっと こづかい はたくなんざ じつに 見{み}上{あ}げた もんですよ

Comment: Deleted my answer because you edited your question to the extent that makes me look like I did not even read your question but answered it anyway.

Comment: The sentence is incomplete, and the last だ is a filler.

Comment: @l'électeur   I'm very sorry that I did not mention that I missed the first 2 bubble text sentences. Next time, I'll also give a comment to the thing I have updated later.

Answer (score 3):

[@user4092](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4092) is right: だ (助動詞 used like a filler) + は.

だ[助動] 2. [from デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A0-556047) :

> 終止形「だ」を間投助詞的に用いて、語調を強める意を表す。「それは**だ**、お前が悪いんだよ」

日本国語大辞典 adds that in such usage,

> 「ね」「よ」 などを伴うこともある

so "それはだね", "私がだよ", etc. are also often seen.

Comment: Hadn't been answered so I posted an answer, I made it a community wiki because mostly it was not my effort.